# Open DIV button in New Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window, target

I have seen this answered several ways here in Stack Overflow, but after attempting the solutions nothing is working for my button.  Here is the code I am using:

```
<center>
<div onclick="parent.location='http://google.com'" data-mce-onclick=""><button class="button"><font size=”6”>Visit Google</font></button></div>
</center>
```

The use of `parent.location` causes google to load in the current window.  I have attempted `open.window` `open.window.href` adding `,’_blank’` and several other adjustments, but for whatever reason it still loads in the same window, or I lose the ability to link at all.  What is the simplest way to adjust this code?

Comment: Well you clearly haven't searched much...and in the 00's as your code is quite outdated... anyway the method to open a new window is `window.open` , not `open.window`. Another thing : don't use inline javascript. And a last thing : you're currently trying to re-invent the hyperlink, there's no point in doing this, simply use an anchor tag and style it as you wish (= as a button if you want...)

Comment: `window.open(this.href, '_blank');` if its a tag. In your case this.href is the link provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parent.location` references the same window.  And I don't know where you got the ideas for the other things you tried, but [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) seems to be what you're looking for:

```
<div onclick="window.open('http://google.com')" data-mce-onclick="">
  <button class="button"><font size=”6”>Visit Google</font></button>
</div>
```

It's worth noting also that you're using very old and deprecated tags.  `center` and `font` should be replaced with CSS styling.

Comment: Thanks David, that fixed it for me.  I had tried this option before but was leaving out the parenthesis.  I will award it here in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.open documented here 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp